# Parse float from string (v-lang)

Tags: parsing, casting, vlang

How to convert string values like `'2 263.32'`, `'592.06'` to float numbers (`f64`) in [V-language](https://github.com/vlang/v)?

*UPD:* solved in this way:

`'1 456.93'.replace(' ', '').f32()` == (float) `1456.93`.

Of courcse, this is a workaround and won't work with strings like `'$1,592.13'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'592.06'.f64()`. I don't think having a whitespace in the number will work currently but you can use underscore instead: `'2_263.32'.f64()`

Comment: `'1 456.93'.replace(' ', '').f32()` works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `strconv` module

```
import strconv
f := strconv.atof64(592.06) ?
```